# How to get the value of TYPO3 backend_layout in your fluid content element?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, fluid-styled-content

I need to get the value of the field `backend_layout` in my `fluid content element`.

Via `<f:debug />` I get the value in my `page template`, but not at the level of the `content element`.

Answer (score 2):

try to set the following in setup typoscript for "page":

```
page {

    # e.g. inside your page template "10"
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        # ...

        variables {

            # access this with {layout} in your fluid templates
            layout = TEXT
            layout {
                data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
                override {
                    field = backend_layout
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, great success

Comment: Note that `{layout}` mentioned above always prepends `pagets__` to the backend layout name. I used `{layout}` like this in a fluid if statement... `<f:if condition="{data.uid} != 1 && {layout} == 'pagets__sidebar'"><f:then>Do something</f:then></f:if>`. This returns true if you're not on page with `uid` equal to `1` and you are on a page that is using the backend layout of `sidebar`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `vhs` extension and the view helper `v:page.info` available [there](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/2.1.2/Page/InfoViewHelper.html) or pass the variable somehow (TypoScript, register, etc.) down to your content elements.